# Logical error in toy program (using Switch for calculator operators)

Tags: java, calculator

I m building this toy program (a simple calculator with a GUI) but I can't make it work. While the compiler shows that everything is fine, when I hit "=" to get a result it shows 0.0. I suppose this is happening because:

a) the result variable is instantiated in the OperatorButtons so it's value is set to 0 once the instance is closed. If this is the case, should I put it in main section?

b) my idea to use switch in the OperatorButtons is wrong for some reason.

//Declaring Variables

```
      private char previousOperator='+';
      private char currentOperator=' ';
      private double number1;
      private double result=0;
      private String numInStr="";
```

//Setting the event handler for the number buttons

```
     private void NmbrBtn(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                         
            numInStr+=evt.getActionCommand();
            number1=Double.parseDouble(numInStr);
            tfDisplay.setText(numInStr);
        }
```

//Setting the event handler for the Operators (where the program has to keep track of the previous and the current operator)

```
     private void OperatorButtons(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                  
            previousOperator=currentOperator;        
            currentOperator=evt.getActionCommand().charAt(0);


                switch (previousOperator){
                    case '+':result+=number1;
                    case '-':result-=number1;
                    case '*':result*=number1;
                    case '/':result/=number1;
                }

                numInStr="";

        }
```

//Setting the handler for the "="

```
        private void EqualsBtn(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           

            tfDisplay.setText(result+"");
        }
```

Comment: Already beaten to it: `break` for each case.

Comment: By removing the switch statement from the "=" operator did the job. That's for possible future reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switch` cases, in Java and nearly every other language that uses the `switch` construct, *fall through* to the one below them unless you use `break`. That is, if `previousOperator` is `+`, then not only does `result+=number1;` run, but then also `result-=number1;` and the other two statements after it. If `previousOperator` is `*`, then both `result*=number1;` and `result/=number1;` run.

Adding `break` tells the compiler you don't want that:

```
switch (previousOperator){
    case '+':result+=number1;break;
    case '-':result-=number1;break;
    case '*':result*=number1;break;
    case '/':result/=number1;break;
}
```

---

Subjective: Spaces and such enhance readability, consider:

```
switch (previousOperator){
    case '+': result += number1; break;
    case '-': result -= number1; break;
    case '*': result *= number1; break;
    case '/': result /= number1; break;
}
```

Note how much easier it is to see the operator being applied. If a case has more than one statement other than `break` (or, in my view, even if it doesn't), use a line break and indentation:

```
switch (previousOperator){
    case '+':
        result += number1;
        break;
    case '-':
        result -= number1;
        break;
    case '*':
        result *= number1;
        break;
    case '/':
        result /= number1;
        break;
}
```

...but for just one statement other than `break`, it's not uncommon to put them all on one line. With spaces.

Comment: SONAR actually warns against using switch statements for this exact reason (that breaks are frequently forgotten) and suggests replacing them with if/else if/else blocks.

Comment: @Joeblade: Better yet, use a decent lint tool, so you get the benefits of `switch` (table dispatching) but get gently (or not so gently) prodded if you forget `break`.

Comment: That was really helpful, thank you. My mind had chosen to erase break all together :P That fixed the problem partially. So the value of result is saved after all...